# Random value when UIButton pressed

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to be able to random a value when a UIButton is pressed.

I tried if else statement but it seems to be crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ButtonName addTarget:self action:@selector(randomize) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) randomize
{

    random = arc4random()%5;

    switch (random)
    {
        case 0:
                *condition*
             break;
        case 1:
                *condition*
             break;

.....

}
```

hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate and output a random number to the console everytime you press the button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithStyle:UIButtonStyleRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self withAction:@selector(random) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRect(50,50,100,50);

    [self.view addsubview:button];
}

- (void)random
{
    NSLog(@"%i",arc4random());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an IBAction to your button, and do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    myValue = arc4random() % MAX_VALUE;
}
```

This will generate a random number from [0, MAX_VALUE), and store it in the (int) variable `myValue`.